# NUnit CategoryName

Tags: selenium, nunit

I tried for the first time using TestCase as explained [here](https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/nunit-parameterized-test-examples/).

I normally got the category name (for debug purpose) like this:

```
lstCategories = (System.Collections.IList)NUnit.Framework.TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Properties["Category"];
```

and then found the category name like this:

```
(string)lstCategories[0]
```

But when I use TestCase I could not get it (it is empty).
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you setup your `[Test]` method as in the example which you provided? There is an example of how to pass data to the test method:

```
        private static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> AddBrowserConfs()
        {
            yield return new TestCaseData("chrome", "72.0", "Windows 10");
            yield return new TestCaseData("internet explorer", "11.0", "Windows 10");
            yield return new TestCaseData("Safari", "11.0", "macOS High Sierra");
            yield return new TestCaseData("MicrosoftEdge", "18.0", "Windows 10");
        }
 
        [Test, TestCaseSource("AddBrowserConfs")]
        public void DuckDuckGo_TestCaseSource_Demo(String browser, String version, String os)
        {
```

As you can see, values from `AddBrowserConfs` are passed as arguments in `DuckDuckGo_TestCaseSource_Demo`. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your post. I asked about printing the category name for debug purpose into the output window (or console). I have a problem with that, not with the test case source :)

Comment: Could you provide a bigger fragment of your code? To see how the method is setup together with annotations.

Comment: Thanks again. 
When I specify a category like this: 
[Category("TestCategory1")]
And get its name like this:
var cat = (string)((System.Collections.IList)TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Properties["Category"])[0];

While using a simple Test with no cases - it's working ok.
If I specify test cases, I get an error: 
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index'

Answer (score 0):

With test cases you are not getting Category name because its not set properly. You need to set it with each test cases as below:

```
    [Test]
    [TestCase(12, 4, Category = "MyCat")]
    [TestCase(10, 6, Category = "MyCat")]
    public void Test2(int a, int b)
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(a + b, 16);
        var catName = TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Properties.Get("Category").ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(catName);
    }
```

OR if you are using TestCaseSource, add Category name as below:

```
[Test]
[TestCaseSource(typeof(AddCases), Category = "MyCat")]
public void Test2(int a, int b)
{
    Assert.AreEqual(a + b, 16);
}

public class AddCases : IEnumerable
{
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return new object[] { 8, 8 };
        yield return new object[] { 10, 6 };
        yield return new object[] { 12, 4 };
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.